# If words are not string replace

Tags: vba, excel

I'm failing at creating a VBA for replacing some values in a column.

The criteria:

I have 2 words in a string.   If those 2 words are not in a column then replace the cell with a variable.

Example:

```
day
day
day
free
day
Busy
day
Busy
```

String: (day, Free)

if a word does not contain in String then replace with "off"

Conclusion:

```
Day
Day
Day
Free
Day
Off
Day
Off
```

Comment: You mention you are trying to create a VBA for this.  Can you please provide what you've tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Let's just help him lol

```
Sub DateSelectandClean()
    Dim str, iRow, iCol
    str = "day, free"
    iRow = 1
    iCol = 1
    Do
        If (Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> "") Then
            If (InStr(1, str, Cells(iRow, iCol).Value) = 0) Then
                Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = "off"
            End If
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Given that Column A contains:

```
day  
day  
day  
free  
day  
Busy  
day  
Busy
```

Output will be:

```
day  
day  
day  
free  
day  
off  
day  
off
```

Comment: We all are here to help. But probably you are neglecting the remarks added by two senior members. This isn't a good habit.

Comment: this is noted sir :(

Comment: Thank you...Didn't mean to get you in trouble,